# Mysql create new table with array data or update

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

can anyone help me to create a new or update an existing table with new data?
I have a table "users" with columns: id, name, phone, email, city and i want to change all the data on the column phone with the new values that i have.
I tried to update but never worked. I used the code:

```
UPDATE users SET phone = '' WHERE phone IN ('91111', '9222', '9333');
```

I updated the column phone to ''

```
id     name     phone     email       city
-------------------------------------------------
1      john               1@1.pt      PT
2      Sue                2@2.pt      RU
3      Ted                2@2.pt      SP
```

to

```
id     name     phone     email       city
-------------------------------------------------
1      john    teste      1@1.pt      PT
2      Sue     t          2@2.pt      RU
3      Ted     teste3     2@2.pt      SP
```

Comment: What is the datatype of the `phone` column?

Comment: It works for me: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a319d8/1

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question? You're not creating a new table, there's no array data.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Add some sample current table data and the expected result.

Comment: The data is text, not numeric like i shown sorry and the title i forgot to include update as well